# How to access a jar of jars in clojure?

Tags: java, jar, clojure, libgdx

I am using lein for a Clojure project where I am trying to use the [libgdx](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/) package in [clojars](https://clojars.org/org.clojars.amu/libgdx/versions/0.9.2). The jar file that is installed from that package contains a lib folder with multiple jars for gdx.

$ jar tf org/clojars/amu/libgdx/0.92/libgdx-0.9.2.jar

```
lib/ 
lib/gdx-openal.jar 
lib/gdx-backend-jogl-natives.jar
lib/gdx-backend-android.jar 
lib/gdx-backend-lwjgl.jar
lib/gdx-backend-lwjgl-natives.jar 
lib/gdx.jar 
lib/gdx-natives.jar
lib/gdx-backend-jogl.jar
```

I have also added the following dependency into my project.clj: [org.clojars.amu/libgdx "0.9.2"]

What I am unsure of is how I go about accessing each of the jars inside of the libgdx jar with the :use and :require keywords?

```
(ns game.core
  (:import (libgdx.gdx Game)) <- does not work
```

I've put a public repository for the lein project up on github here: [Project Link](https://github.com/jwthomp/cljlibgdx-test)

I'll update the project so that it works as an example for others once I have it solved.

Comment: I'm not Java expert, but it looks like, that Clojure's classloader doesn't see embedded jars...

Comment: The default classloader for the JVM doesn't support nested jars. There  are third-party classloaders like [One-JAR](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) that support nested jars, but including a third-party classloader seems a bit overkill here. Why don't you just unzip the libgdx jar and then push each nested jar individually to Clojars yourself?

Comment: A common approach to the problem is to create an [uberjar](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/src/leiningen/uberjar.clj)

Comment: @skuro Unfortunately this doesn't work anymore with tagged reader literals.

Comment: Also, the import is wrong ``libgdx.gdx Game`` => ``com.badlogix.gdx Gdx``.

Answer (score 0):

An uberjar won't work because the file in clojars is not a normal jar file containing classes but is a really a file that you are meant to download, extract the necessary jars and place them on the classpath or lib for your project.

While you could write a fancy classloader to do that, that goes contrary to the [instructions from the libgdx site](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ProjectSetup) which include the instruction:

```
 Download the nightly zip and place gdx.jar and gdx-sources.jar in the libs folder.
```

The more appropriate thing to do is to extract the jars from that download jar and add them to clojars and refer to them individually.  That or just add them to your local classpath or repo.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, but if they packaged it like that, then maybe they already provided the fancy classloader that will do the right thing?

Also, your import does not look correct to me. Should be vectors (not lists) correct?

e.g.

```
(ns warscore.swing
  (:import
   [java.awt Color ]
   [java.awt.event MouseEvent]
   [javax.swing DefaultCellEditor JCheckBox JLabel JTable JTextField ]
   [javax.swing.table DefaultTableCellRenderer ]))
```